# Read chunk of 6 unique characters in the file, map the string of all possible 6 letter chunks of unique characters to a unique value

Tags: python-3.x, file, file-handling

Given a file `file.txt` consisting of billions of characters.

**Problem:**

Read the file and for each chunk of 6 unique characters in the file and map the string of all possible 6 letter chunks of unique characters to a unique value.

**Here is my code**

```
with open("file.txt") as file1:
    string = ''.join(file1.readlines())
    unique_dict = {}
    i=0
    while i <= len(string)-6:
        if len(set(string[i:i+6])) == len(string[i:i+6]):
            if string[i:i+6] in unique_dict.values():
                pass
            else:
                unique_dict[i] = string[i:i+6]
            i = i+5
        i += 1
    print(unique_dict)
```

**And `file.txt` contains**

```
abcdefghijkabcdef
```

Instead of billions of characters I've taken minimum characters for understanding purpose.

**Here is the output:**

```
{0: 'abcdef', 6: 'ghijka'}
```

**Is there any other efficient way to do this in less comparisons?**

Comment: Can't you just precompute all the possible characters combinations and assign to each of them a unique code?

Comment: This method is useful for 1000-10000 characters text file but what about a file which contains billions of characters. How much memory will require? That's why I am asking for a efficient solution.

Comment: As i already told you I would precompute all the possible characters combinations without even looking at the file.